# Running Tkinter dependent code alongside mainloop without GUI freeze

Tags: python, multithreading, image, user-interface, tkinter

I am writing a simple image viewer that lets the user flip very quickly through tens of thousands of images, about 100 at a time. The images are files on disk.

In order for the viewer to function, it must continuously preload images ahead of the user's current one (or the viewer would be unusably sluggish).

The basic recipe that I'm using to display the images in a grid of Tkinter labels, is the following (this has been tested and works):

```
def load_image(fn):
    image = Image.open(fn)
    print "Before photoimage"
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    print "After photoimage"

label.config(image=load_image("some_image.png")
```

I need the ImageTk.PhotoImage instance to display the image on a label. I have implemented two different approaches, each with an associated problem.

**First approach:**
Launch a separate thread which pre-loads the images:

```
def load_ahead():
    for fn in images:
        cache[fn] = load_image()
threading.Thread(target=load_ahead).start()
top.mainloop()
```

This works quite well on my Linux machine. However, on another machine (which happens to be running Windows, and compiled with pyinstaller), a deadlock seems to happen. "Before Photoimage" is printed, and then the program freezes, which suggests that the loader thread gets stuck at creating the ImageTk.PhotoImage object. Musst the creation of an ImageTk.PhotoImage object happen within the main (Tkinter mainloop's) thread? Is the creation of PhotoImage computationally expensive, or is negligible compared to actually loading the image from disk?

**Second approach:**
In order to circumvent this possible requirement of PhotoImage objects being created from within Tkiner's mainloop thread, I resorted to Tk.after:

```
def load_some_images():
    #load only 10 images. function must return quickly to prevent freezing GUI
    for i in xrange(10): 
        fn = get_next_image()
        cache[fn] = load_image(fn)
    top.after_idle(load_some_images)

top.after_idle(load_some_images)
```

The problem with this is that, appart from creating additional overhead (ie the image-loading procedure must be broken up into very small chunks since it is competing with the GUI) that it periodically freezes the GUI for the duration of the call, and it seems to consume any keyboard events that happened during its execution.

**Third approach**
Is there a way I can detect pending user events? How can I accomplish something like this?

```
def load_some_images():
    while True:
        try: top.pending_gui_events.get_nowait()
        except: break
        #user is still idle! continuing caching of images
        fn = get_next_image()
        cache[fn] = load_image(fn)
    top.after_idle(load_some_images)

top.after(5,load_some_images)
```

Edit: I have tried using top.tk.call('after','info') to check pending keyboard events. This doesn't always reliably, and the interface is still sluggish/unresponsive.

Thanks in advance for any ideas

Answer (score 2):

I recommend creating an `load_one_image` function rather than a `load_some_images` function. It will be less likely to interfere with the event loop.

Also, as a rule of thumb, a function called via `after_idle` shouldn't reschedule it self with `after_idle`. The reason is that `after_idle` will block until the idle event queue is drained. If you keep adding stuff on to the queue while the queue is being processed, it never gets completely drained. This could be the reason why your GUI seems to hang once in a while with your second approach.

Try `after(5, ...)` rather than `after_idle(...)`. If your system can create an image in less than 5ms, you can process 100 images in about half a second, which is probably fast enough to give a pretty snappy interface. You can tweak the delay to see how it affects the overall feel of the app.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried several variation of this.  The significant overhead introduced by this method causes the image loading to be at least 5x slower. Despite this, the GUI is still pretty sluggish, ignoring keyboard events and freezing randomly for seconds. Even if I'm loading just one image, when the time comes to load a large one or if the disk is slow to read the file, those 1-2 seconds or however long it takes will inevitably be felt by the user.

Comment: I think this pretty much rules out putting the IO-intensive loading of images inside the mainloop. I tried the third approach (using self.tk.call('after', 'info') to check for pending user events), which maybe was a bit better, but still slow and unreliable(the events weren't always detected quickly) . It seems the only approach to make the UI responsive and not prone to random hanging is to do the image-loading on a separate thread.

Comment: @ealfonso: `after_info` only tells you about events scheduled with `after`, it knows nothing about any other type of event.

Comment: @ealfonso: how big are the images, and how old is your computer? On a 2013 macbook pro, I can directly load 100 1300x600 .gif images in about .5 seconds.